# How can we turn off some LinkedIn login permissions to our website?

Tags: authentication, linkedin

Our website is allowing logins from LinkedIn, but we are asking too many permissions from users.

The permission we are asking are:

1. Use your name and photo
2. Use the primary email address associated with your LinkedIn account
3. Post, comment and like posts on your behalf

Is there any way to turn off the third one?

Answer (score 1):

You probably use a share plugin together with the login plugin?

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context

Comment: No, we use hybrid auth to enable login

Comment: This: https://hybridauth.github.io/hybridauth/userguide/IDProvider_info_LinkedIn.html ? Then you might want to read the documentation "For LinkedIn you can configure several extra options:

scope: An array of permissions you want to request from the user. Possible values: "r_liteprofile", "r_emailaddress", "w_member_social".